# Moving a file on an ftp site using php cURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I have a need to rename a file after download using php cURL.

Here's what I have:

```
    $localFile = fopen($fileName, 'w');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $localFile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$ftpUsername:$ftpPassword");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, array("RNFR $remoteFile", "RNTO $remoteFile.downloaded"));

    curl_exec($curl) === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
    }
```

If I remove the CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE part, the file downloads fine.  I've also tried a couple different combinations of the postquote array:

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, array("RNFR $remoteFile RNTO $remoteFile.downloaded"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, array("-RNFR $remoteFile", "-RNTO $remoteFile.downloaded"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, array("-RNFR $remoteFile -RNTO $remoteFile.downloaded"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, array("rename $remoteFile $remoteFile.downloaded"));
```

The error I've been getting look like:

```
ERROR  : QUOT string not accepted: -RNFR $remoteFile -RNTO $remoteFile.downloaded
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anybody finds themselves here in the future.

My issue was that `$remoteFile` resolved to something like `/remote_folder/remote_file.txt`, but since my ftp connection already included the folder, something like `ftp://www.example.com/remote_folder/remote_file.txt`, I wasn't supposed to specify the folder in `RNFR` and `RNTO`.

Comment: Then finally the **two** commands to add to the "CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE" list are: `RNFR remote_file.txt` and `RNTO remote_file_downloaded.txt`.